# How do I use the NLTK sent_tokenize function to loop through a data frame column containing text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have the following data frame (df) that starts off as a .csv with a few columns in it and which gets loaded into a Jupyter notebook. I would like to use one of the columns as a corpus for nlp scripting.  when I attempt to run sent_tokenize (or even word_tokenize), I get an error.  Below is my script and resulting error:

```py
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
my_data.head()  # one column in particular, "col5", will have my text data of interest
data = my_data  # to feed it into a generic shorter generic variable
data_corpus = data["col5"]  # creates a separate data frame that I will use as my corpus of interest

TEXT_COLUMN = "col5"
text = data[TEXT_COLUMN]

corpus_tokenized = sent_tokenize(text) # here is where I am running problems
```

resulting error:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
----> 1 corpus_tokenized = sent_tokenize(text)

NameError: name 'text' is not defined

```py
# When I apply the sent_tokenize function to a single text instance, there are no problems:
this_sentence = "this sentence is in English"

['this sentence is in English']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apply` lets you apply functions on a row wise or column wise fashion. So:

```
data["tokenized_text"] = data["col5"].apply(sent_tokenize)
```

Should work

Comment: I appreciate the help!  However, when I try the above suggestion, I get the following Python error verbiage:     TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: I'll need a sample of  `col5` rows to be able to help you. I assumed it was a string column

Comment: @ Juan C:  strange thing happened.  When I loaded the original data into Python, the "col5" column had some empty rows here and there, and because of that, sent_tokenize function apparently didn't like that and it would not work.  When I replaced those nulls with a dummy text like "nodata", and then went back and ran your suggestion, it worked fine.  Thank you!